# Android Fragment not saving UI State on pressing Back Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

I am running into a issue with my use case. its pretty basic usecase. I have a main activity and 2 Fragments. The main activity doesnt have much UI. All it does is replace its container with FirstFragment.

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, FirstFragment.newInstance())
            .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
    }
}
```

FirstFragment has 2 buttons - initializeButton and button1 with initializeButton in enable state by default while button1 is enabled only after pressing initializeButton.
Once Button1 is pressed after initializeButton it launches the SecondFragment. Following is the code which does that .

```
        requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.container, SecondFragment.newInstance())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```

Now, this Launches Secondfragment properly. now when I press the back button when in Fragment2 the behaviour that I want is that the first fragment is launched with both the buttons in the enabled state. Instead, it is going to the default state in the First Fragment(initialize button in Enabled state while button1 in Disabled state). Appreciate any feedback. Thanks

MainActivity

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.container, FirstFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit()
        }
    }
}
```

MainActivity layout

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />
```

FirstFragment

```
class FirstFragment : Fragment() {

    companion object {
        fun newInstance() = FirstFragment()
    }

    private lateinit var viewModel: SharedViewModel
    private lateinit var initializeButton: Button
    private lateinit var button1: Button
    private lateinit var newview: View

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            newview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false)
        }
        return  newview
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initializeButton = view.findViewById(R.id.button1)
        initializeButton.setOnClickListener{
            button1.isEnabled = true
        }
        button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.button2)
        button1.setOnClickListener{
            requireActivity().supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, SecondFragment.newInstance())
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
        outState.putBoolean("initState", initializeButton.isEnabled)
        outState.putBoolean("button1State", button1.isEnabled)
    }

    override fun onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewStateRestored(savedInstanceState)
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            initializeButton.isEnabled = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("initState")
            button1.isEnabled = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("button1State")
        }
    }
```

Fragment first layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".FirstFragment">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/initialize"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="@string/button2"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"/>

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

SecondFragment

```
class SecondFragment : Fragment() {
    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
                              savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false)
    }

    companion object {
            fun newInstance() = SecondFragment()
    }
}
```

Secondfragment layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/info"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/second_fragment"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Large"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: did you try to save the state onPause?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is there any particular reason why you are replacing the fragment? If not, you can just simply add it instead of replacing and that will ensure the state gets maintained.

Your code will change like this

```kotlin
   .add(R.id.container, SecondFragment.newInstance())
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit()
```

Comment: Add will overlap the first fragment. I want to move to new screen

Comment: @KSP It will overlap but the fragment on top will take priority if you have the proper XML attributes namely the background color, clickable as true and focusable as true. Rest I would suggest you check and debug once if inside your `onViewStateRestored` you are getting the proper data.

Comment: .add(R.id.container, SecondFragment.newInstance())
                    .hide(this)
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .commit()  - So the above change did the trick for my use case. just that when i press the back button it deletes the 2nd fragment.

Comment: @KSP If it worked for you, you can mark it as the correct answer for other people to refer.